# Can't import a Swagger definition description into WSO2 Publisher

Tags: wso2, swagger, swagger-ui

The Swagger generated definition is automatically generated from my jersey/java project.

The swagger pom.xml conf looks like:

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>     
     <configuration>
                    <apiSources>
                    <apiSource>
                        <locations>com.rest.resources</locations>
                        <apiVersion>1.0</apiVersion>
                        <basePath>http://server:8080/context/api-docs/</basePath>

                        <swaggerDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/api-docs/</swaggerDirectory>
                        <swaggerUIDocBasePath>http://server:8080/context/api-docs/</swaggerUIDocBasePath>
                        <useOutputFlatStructure>false</useOutputFlatStructure>

                    </apiSource>
                </apiSources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And the dependency:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.10</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The generated files are: services.json + one json file per resource

The service.json looks like:

```
{
  "apiVersion" : "1.0",
  "swaggerVersion" : "1.2",
  "apis" : [ {
    "path" : "/user.{format}",
    "description" : "Operations about user"
  } ],
  "basePath" : "http://server:8080/context/api-docs/"
}
```

All the generated files are stored in the same directory.

When i try to import the services.json in WSO2 Publisher 1.7 , i get the following error:

```
org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid uri 'http://server:8080/context/api-docs/service.json/users.{format}': escaped absolute path not valid (http#194)
at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:575)
at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:432)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
```

I can access the service.json with the given url to wso2.

Is there something wrong with the generated swagger ?

Comment: How did you generate that spec exactly? It's not exactly valid.

Comment: @webron : i just added the pom.xml config

Comment: Okay, the you're using the maven plugin. It produces an invalid spec as the basePath isn't part of the resource listing, but that's not causing the issue.

Comment: I don't know what WSO2 is, but it's trying to read the url http://server:8080/context/api-docs/service.json/users.{format} which is indeed invalid. It's a bit difficult to discuss this in comments here.